# Why discontinuous density of states will cause isolated energy pole when perturbation is applied to it?

Tags: condensed-matter, density-of-states

Recently I'm struggling with Green's functions. It is said that when `G(E)` diverges around `E_0`  ,the density of states at `E_0` is discontinuous and therefore will lead to isolated energy pole when perturbation is applied to it.

I already knew that density of states is related to the imaginary part of Green's  function, so when Green's  function diverges, density of states should also diverge.

But why it is discontinuous and why this leads to new  isolated energy pole when perturbation is applied? Does that mean any perturbation ,no matter how small it is, can cause a new isolated energy eigenstate?

Besides, What kind of information can we get from density of states except its definition?

Answer (score 1):

**1-** We need to clarify what type of Green's function we are talking about. The most relevant one for our purposes is probably the retarded Green's function which for an interacting system is given by (omitting momentum and other indices):
$$G_R(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{G_R^0(\epsilon)^{-1}-\Sigma_R(\epsilon)}$$
Where $G_R^0$ is the Green's function for free system and $\Sigma_R$ is the self energy, which contains the effect of interactions on 1-particle excitations of the system.

**2-** Let's consider the non-interacting case first. The bare Green's function $G_R^0$ is analytic in the upper half of the complex plane. This means that, it is also analytic on the real axis. But it has a pole below the real axis with an infinitesimal imaginary part, the amplitude of the imaginary part gives the decay rate of free particles (which is zero, so they are stable in the free regime). For example we take:

$$G_R^0(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon-\epsilon_o+i\delta^+} $$

Where $\epsilon_0$ is the energy of bare single particle excitations and $\delta^+$ is a very small positive constant. Therefore we have:
$$ \text{Re}G_R^0(\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon-\epsilon_0}{(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)^2+\delta^2}$$
$$ \text{Im}G_R^0(\epsilon)=-\frac{\delta^+}{(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)^2+\delta^2}=-\pi \delta(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)$$
So when we take the limit $\delta\to 0$ the real and imaginary parts become discontinuous near the energy of free particles. Most importantly, the imaginary part has a sharp peak at the energy of free particles.

**3-** Now we consider the effect of interaction. When we turn the interactions on $\Sigma_R$ becomes non-zero. We decompose it in terms of its real and imaginary parts:
$$ \Sigma_R(\epsilon)=\Sigma_R'(\epsilon)+i\Sigma_R''(\epsilon)$$
The retarded Green's function vanishes for negative time arguments($t<0$) after Fourier transforming it to real space. Because of this, the imaginary part of $\Sigma_R$ should be non-positive for all values of energy. When we calculate the real and imaginary parts of (interacting) Green's function, we get:

$$\text{Re}G_R(\epsilon)=\frac{\epsilon-\epsilon_0-\Sigma_R'(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon-\epsilon_0-\Sigma_R'(\epsilon))^2+(\delta-\Sigma_R''(\epsilon))^2} $$

$$\text{Im}G_R(\epsilon)=-\frac{\delta-\Sigma_R''(\epsilon)}{(\epsilon-\epsilon_0-\Sigma_R'(\epsilon))^2+(\delta-\Sigma_R''(\epsilon))^2} $$

**We need to be careful here**, Since the real and imaginary parts of self energy are not necessarily zero, the Green's function is not necessarily discontinuous anymore at any values of energy. This is due to the fact the even when we send $\delta\to 0$ the imaginary part of $\Sigma_R$ can be finite, preventing a singularity of $G_R$ near the real axis.

**If** the imaginary part of $G_R$ has a peak with finite width at values of energy satisfying the equation(possibly, for exceptions see below):
$$\epsilon_r-\epsilon_0-\Sigma_R'(\epsilon_r)=0$$
We call these solutions the renormalized energy of particles. So the energy of a single particle is changed due to its interaction with other particles. The width of this peak is given by $-\Sigma_R''(\epsilon_r)$ while its height is proportional to $1/\Sigma_R''(\epsilon_r)$. As a result, the particles may not have well defined, exact energies anymore.

Now, we consider two different cases. Before that, it is helpful to heuristically introduce an important theorem from quantum field theory, called the **optical theorem** which for our purposes states that:

$$\Sigma_R''(\epsilon_r)\propto \text{the probability of particle with energy}\, \epsilon_r \, \text{to decay to anything else}$$

This was also clear from the fact that $\Sigma_R''$ gives us the inverse life-time (=decay rate) of particles.

Now we consider two cases:

**First:** And this is more common in high energy physics. If the (renormalized) spectrum of all excitations have a finite gap. For example, in a theory of massive relativistic particles where a finite amount of energy ($\sim$ particle mass) is required to excite a particle. In this case, an electron cannot decay into another particles as there are not any possible decay channels for the electron. Here it is said that the electron has an isolated pole. While the interactions change its mass (energy), the Green's function for electrons has a sharp peak at the electrons' renormalized energy. There are other possibilities  for an isolated pole, like when certain symmetries prevent some decay channels, even when the spectrum has gapless particles.

**Second:** With more prevalence in condensed matter physics, is when the spectrum is gapless, like quasi-particle in a fermi liquid. Here the quasi particles can (and do) decay into other quasi particles and quasi holes. Actually, there is a continuum of final states that they can decay into.

Sometimes, this has a benign effect on the spectrum. For example, when $\Sigma_R''$ approaches zero for $\epsilon\to \epsilon_r$ faster than $\epsilon - \epsilon_0-\Sigma_R'$ which makes the small $\delta$ to be important again for energies near the peak and the peak becomes a delta function, just like the interacting case, but with a renormalized value of energy. This happens for fermi liquids, including most of metals.

On the other hand, it may happen that  $\Sigma_R''$ approaches zero with a slower pace than $\epsilon - \epsilon_0-\Sigma_R'$. In this case, the peak at $\epsilon=\epsilon_r$ is significantly suppressed and we may not be able to describe the system in terms of interacting quasi particles anymore. These systems are called non-Fermi liquids. This can happen for example, when an electronic system is near a quantum critical point, where electrons are strongly interacting with nearly gapless excitations of the order parameter field.

About your final question, as we said, the knowledge of the density of states gives you the spectrum of the particles and their life-time. Also it allows you to calculate various physical quantities, like energy, magnetization, particle number which usually involve integrals of the form:

$$ \langle \hat{O} \rangle \propto \int O(\epsilon) F(\epsilon,T) DOS(\epsilon) \, d\epsilon $$

Where $F$ is the distribution function at temperature $T$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your long answer. But still I have some questions.

Comment: The first thing is related to my understanding of  why the imaginary part is related to the lifetime of quasi-particles. Now I think ,due to uncertainty principle, the energy  dispersion times the time dispersion should be finite. So if the imaginary part of Green's function has a delta function peak near a certain energy, it  corresponds to definite energy and therefore infinite lifetime. If it's not delta function shape when we take the limit ,then it the  lifetime is not infinite  and cannot be called quasi-particle. Is this right?

Comment: The second question is related to the explanation of  why  discontinuous density of states  leads  to isolated energy pole when  perturbation turned on. My understanding after reading your answer is as follow. After the perturbation  we should use G instead of G0, so perturbation is in the self energy term.  The discontinuous density  of states means there is energy gap, so when we take the limit  the imaginary part is delta function, it  cannot decay ,so it is an isolated  pole.  I'm  not sure  about it.